# Cannot get awk to work properly inside make

Tags: awk, make

I want to parse a file and bracket each line with `#ifndef` and `#endif`.

For example, starting with:

```
#define X 1
#define Y 2
#define Z 3
```

I want to generate:

```
#ifndef X
#define X 1
#endif
#ifndef Y
#define Y 2
#endif
#ifndef Z
#define Z 3
#end if
```

This `awk` script works in console, but it doesn't work inside `make`:

```
awk '{printf "#ifndef %s\n%s %s %s\n#endif\n", $2, $1, $2, $3}' globals.tmp > globals.h
```

When run inside of `make`, it outputs as follows:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {printf "#ifndef %s\n%s %s %s\n#endif\n", , , , }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {printf "#ifndef %s\n%s %s %s\n#endif\n", , , , }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                             ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {printf "#ifndef %s\n%s %s %s\n#endif\n", , , , }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                               ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {printf "#ifndef %s\n%s %s %s\n#endif\n", , , , }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                 ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {printf "#ifndef %s\n%s %s %s\n#endif\n", , , , }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                  ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

So it's obviously not pulling in the fields. I tried playing around with `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`: adding single, double and triple backslashes, changing the quotes, etc., nothing works. I know `awk` and `make` can be quirky, wondering if there is some "gotcha" I'm not getting?

Comment: You have to double the `$` characters to keep `make` from evaluating them).  That, and other useful information is in the manual page.  (this is a duplicate, by the way).

Comment: Bracket each line, or bracket each line starting `#define`? There's potentially quite a difference. (Unless every single line is a `#define`, of course. But you don't state that.)

Comment: @roaima - bracket each line, as it says

Comment: @Buddy I know that's what it says. I was seeking confirmation you really meant that, because with lines other than those of the form `#define K X`  your `awk` script would fail with its expectations of `$1`, `$2`, `$3`. So since you've confirmed that it's for "each line", what should happen when one or more of `$1`, `$2`, `$3` are empty?

Comment: @roaima - the file is created by parsing a compile log to pull out all global definitions, with all lines are formatted as above - some definitions are already covered, and will cause a build error if redefined - the `#ifndef` `#endif` lines are used to protect against redefinition